# Allow Chrome extension to access RESTAPI

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm building a chrome extension and Rest API. Now I'm in the phase of connecting them, but I have some security concerns.

The extension should call API to get some data. **This data is not specific to a User.**

***So, the question how to make sure that my API can be called only from Chrome Extension?***

I was thinking about adding some specific header, but this won't specifically solve the problem.

I've started looking into OAuth2 with allows third-party apps access to the API, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Well-designed API should require authentication for _**any**_ data requested, even not specific to a user.

Comment: Agree, and I know how to restrict API access to specific IPs or Domains.
But with chrome extension it's different cause it is on the user device and you can't restrict access using this options. That's why I'm looking for something else

Comment: It seems that we're talking about different things. IP/domain restrictions have no relation to authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The extension runs in the user's browser.

The user's browser is completely under the control of the user.

The user can inspect whatever HTTP requests their browser makes (including those which perform OAuth).

Those HTTP requests can be replicated with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, it is not possible, as there is no way to ensure that the other end of a network link is your application.
End user have complete access to your application, you can use user authentication to ensure only valid users use your application.